# How do i setup a wifi adapter on my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B?

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I have a Comfast CF-WU810N V2.0 - 2.4GHz 802.11b/g/n 150Mbps USB 2.0 Wireless Wi-Fi Network Adapter. It works with most of my devices but not with my Raspberry Pi. I want to set it up with my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B running windows 10 iot core. How do I do it? Please Help!

Comment: This is not a general forum but a site for questions about programming and tools and their usage directly related to programming.

Comment: It is related due to having WiFi on the network is required for remote debugging with visual studio.

Comment: if is answer, please mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today the only supported WiFi dongle is the official Raspberry Pi dongle.  This is known and actively being worked on.